# Как записать результаты парсинга из сохранённой страницы в csv файл?

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup, csv

Использую вот такой код, пытаюсь вытащить данные из сохранённой html-страницы:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import codecs
import os
import lxml
import csv

f = codecs.open("ZHVACHKA.html", 'r', 'utf-8')
html = f.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
products = soup.findAll("div", class_="tovar")
products_json = [products]




for product in products:
    try:
        product_name = product.find("p")  # вытащил значение из тега по атрибуту
        product_price = product.find("div", class_="tovar-price").text  # вытащил цену
        

        table_head = product_name, product_price
        product_names = table_head[0]
        product_prices = table_head[1]

        with open("Products.csv", "w", encoding='utf-8') as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerow(
                (
                    product_names,
                    product_prices,
                )
            )



    except Exception as ex:
        print()
```

На выходе: создаётся файл без заголовков, с одной строкой, где текст на русском заменён какой-то кракозяброй. Не могу понять в чём причина, кусок html прилагаю.

```
<div class="tovar">
                            <div class="image-tovar" tid="DpR5YsiqGI" name_eng="zhevatelnaya-rezinka-exit-s-myatoy-bez-sahara-1">  
                            </div>                                 
                            <div class="tovar-schet" tid="DpR5YsiqGI">
                                <div id="minus" tid="DpR5YsiqGI" price="32.9">−</div>      
                                <div class="kol-vo" id="kol-voDpR5YsiqGI">0</div>
                                <p id="plus" tid="DpR5YsiqGI" price="32.9" name="Жевательная резинка EXIT С мятой без сахара 1/20шт(8699449031342)" magazine_sort="jKZIRdGMXN">+</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="tovar-name" tid="DpR5YsiqGI" name_eng="zhevatelnaya-rezinka-exit-s-myatoy-bez-sahara-1">Жевательная резинка EXIT
С мятой без сахар...</div>
                            <div class="tovar-price">32.9 руб.</div>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="tovar">
                            <div class="image-tovar" tid="bS8oh6XnQa" name_eng="zhevatelnaya-rezinka-dirol-colors-xxl-19gr-ass"> 
                            </div>                                 
                            <div class="tovar-schet" tid="bS8oh6XnQa">
                                <div id="minus" tid="bS8oh6XnQa" price="54.9">−</div>      
                                <div class="kol-vo" id="kol-vobS8oh6XnQa">0</div>
                                <p id="plus" tid="bS8oh6XnQa" price="54.9" name="Жевательная резинка DIROL COLORS XXL 19гр Ассорти фруктовых вкусов 1/18шт(57030852)" magazine_sort="jKZIRdGMXN">+</p>
                            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Для сохранения кириллицы в `CSV-файле` вы должны использовать кодировку `utf-8-sig`, которая сохраняет символы `Unicode` в формате `UTF-8` с `BOM-маркером`.

Так же немного отредактировал Ваш файл, чтобы файл не открывался на перезапись внутри цикла. Это можно заметить по замене структуры Вашего тела кода.

Обратите внимание, что я имплементировал `newline=''`, чтобы избежать дополнительного переноса строки между записями в файле `CSV`.

Добавлены исключения для `product_name` и `product_price`, чтобы избежать ошибок формата `NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'`.

Использовано функцию `writer.writerows()` вместо `writer.writerow()` для записи данных в файл в виде списка списков.

Так же добавил выход из цикла `break`, в дальнейшем пригодится :)

**Решение:**

```python
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import codecs
# import os
# import lxml
import csv

f = codecs.open("ZHVACHKA.html", 'r', 'utf-8')
html = f.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
products = soup.findAll("div", class_="tovar")
products_json = [products]

with open("Products.csv", "w", encoding='utf-8-sig', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(['Product Name', 'Price'])

    for product in products:
        try:
            product_name = product.find("div", class_="tovar-name")
            if product_name is not None:
                product_name = product_name.text.strip()

            product_price = product.find("div", class_="tovar-price")
            if product_price is not None:
                product_price = product_price.text.strip()

            writer.writerows([[product_name, product_price]])

        except Exception as ex:
            print(ex)

        break
```

**Результат выполнения даного кода:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Примечание:**
Если желаете просто одной строчкой, как в оригинале, можете сохранить свой код, тогда лишь замените `utf-8` на `utf-8-sig`

**Тогда результат будет таков:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо! Но переменную '''product_name''' я вытягиваю из тега '''p''', потому что в '''div tovar-name''' название не полное. Поэтому всё засунул в цикл с условием '''writer.writerows(f'{product_name["name"]}, {product_price["price"]}')''', однако теперь у меня каждый символ появляется в каждой ячейке 1 столбца

Comment: Можете попробовать изменить лишь кодировку, как показано в конце, это не должно повлиять на исполнение Вашего кода начального, лишь уберет кракозябриков :)

Comment: Так же можете попробовать использовать `writer.writerows([[product_name["name"], product_price["price"]]])`. Это записывает значения в виде списка, а не строки, что предотвратит разделение значений на отдельные символы. Но это пальцем в небо тыкнул, может поможет :D

Comment: Благодарю, помог метод writer.writerows([[f'{product_name["name"]}, {product_price["price"]}']]), но записывается в файл только одна строка, а не все значения. И да - а как сделать так, чтобы в Product и Price были в разных столбцах, а переменные product_name и product_price записывались по разным столбцам? Совсем недавно стал изучать питон, поэтому многого пока не понимаю

Comment: А у Вас много значений там? Можете включить режим дозаписи, это в строке `with open("Products.csv", "w", encoding='utf-8-sig', newline='') as f:`, замените `w` на `a`. CSV обычно записывают, как у меня на примере было, по крайней мере когда эти данные потом планируют куда-нибудь сплавить, к примеру нейросети. \ Но если нужно, тогда попробуйте как-то так:  до цикла вставьте `rows = []`, потом ваше `writer.writerow([[product_name["name"], product_price["price"]]])` и еще `writer.writerows(rows)`